# Calculate the number of definite months in a period

Tags: python, pandas

The start year, start month, end year, and end month are the inputs (like May'2022 to June'2024). If I need to calculate how many definite months are included in this period (like how many January, March, or December are in this period), how can I achieve this using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html) and [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
s = pd.date_range('2022-05-01','2024-06-01', freq='MS').month_name().value_counts()
print (s)
June         3
May          3
April        2
March        2
July         2
December     2
November     2
October      2
February     2
January      2
September    2
August       2
dtype: int64
```

Last select by index in `Series` called `s`:

```
print (s['January'])
2

print (s['March'])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas date_range is a good helper here

```
import pandas as pd
ym = pd.date_range('2022-05-01','2024-06-01', freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%b").to_list()

print(ym)
def count_month(ym_list, month):
    return(sum(month in s for s in ym_list))

print(count_month(ym, "May"))
print(count_month(ym, "Jan"))
```

and the output is

```
['2022-May', '2022-Jun', '2022-Jul', '2022-Aug', '2022-Sep', '2022-Oct', '2022-Nov', '2022-Dec', '2023-Jan', '2023-Feb', '2023-Mar', '2023-Apr', '2023-May', '2023-Jun', '2023-Jul', '2023-Aug', '2023-Sep', '2023-Oct', '2023-Nov', '2023-Dec', '2024-Jan', '2024-Feb', '2024-Mar', '2024-Apr', '2024-May', '2024-Jun']
3
2
```